# MySQL - join table if x is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query which produces the correct result if each of the `mainMenu`, `subMenu` and `subMenu2` columns in the stories table have a value.

If any of these are null though, then no results are returned. I don't want to use left joins because that will return results when the joined menu is inactive.

```
SELECT * 
FROM stories s
JOIN menu m
    ON s.mainMenu = m.id 
    AND m.menu_active = 1 
JOIN submenu m2
    ON s.subMenu = m2.id
    AND m2.submenu_active = 1
JOIN submenu_L2 m3
    ON s.subMenu2 = m3.id
    AND m3.submenu_L2_active = 1
WHERE s.story_id = 198 
AND s.story_active = 1
```

Is there a way to only join the table if the relevant column in the stories table is not null?

So something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stories s
if s.mainMenu IS NOT NULL then
JOIN menu m
    ON s.mainMenu = m.id 
    AND m.menu_active = 1 
end if
JOIN sub me...
```

Comment: Take a look at left join. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp. It does not include non matching rows (or in your case null).

Comment: couldn't you check whether the value IS NULL inside the ON condition for the next join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mukus. 
Sounds like you want a LEFT JOIN.

A LEFT JOIN will return EVERYTHING from Table 'stories' and data from Table 'menu' where they join.

```
SELECT * 
FROM stories s
LEFT JOIN menu m
    ON s.mainMenu = m.id 
    AND m.menu_active = 1
LEFT JOIN sub me...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `left outer join` with more logic in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stories s LEFT JOIN
     menu m
     ON s.mainMenu = m.id AND m.menu_active = 1 JOIN
     submenu m2
     ON s.subMenu = m2.id AND m2.submenu_active = 1 LEFT JOIN
     submenu_L2 m3
     ON s.subMenu2 = m3.id AND m3.submenu_L2_active = 1
WHERE s.story_id = 198 AND s.story_active = 1 AND
      (s.mainMenue is null or m.id is not null);
```